# Complete Ordinary Differential Equation $(2 x y^2 + 2 y) + (2 y x^2 + 2 x) y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

We have differential equation:

$$(2 x y^2 + 2 y) + (2 y x^2 + 2 x) y' = 0$$

We can easily check that it is a complete differential equation and with solving methods of Complete differential equation I found that it is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y^2 + 2xy) = 0$$

from this we got:

$$x^2y^2 + 2xy = C \implies xy(xy+2) = C$$

But when I used Wolframalpha and some other Differential Equation solvers on the Internet, they gave me $xy=C$.

I know they actually divided the equation by $2(xy+1)$ and solved the equation: $$y + x y' = 0$$

But I don't know which answer is actually correct? Or which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions are correct.

Note that if $xy=C$, then $$xy(xy+2)=C(C+2)=K$$ and If $xy(xy+2)=K$ you can solve for $xy$ and get $xy=C$ for some constant $C$

The preferred solution is then the simpler one, that is $$xy=C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2y^2 + 2xy = C$$
$$x^2y^2 + 2xy +1= C+1$$
$$(xy+1)^2=C+1$$
$$xy+1=\mp \sqrt{C+1}$$
$$xy=-1\mp \sqrt{C+1}$$
or
$$xy=K$$